# Command line to delete all folders with Subfolder/*/FolderToDelete in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, directory

so I would like to have something similar to

```
   @RD /S /Q Plugins/*/Generated
```

So it will delete all the "Generated" folders inside all the different folders inside the "Plugins" folder.

Can it be possible?

Thanks very much for your answers.

Cheers,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (untested):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /ad plugins') do echo rd /s /q "plugins\%%b\Generated"
```

Where : This is a batch line; reduce each `%%` to `%` if running from the prompt

The `echo` command is for safety to *show* what the routine proposes to do. delete the `echo` keyword to activate the deletion after verifying that the commands are correct.